# Wagtail: Intermittent CSRF Verification Error

Tags: django, wagtail

When saving a draft, I have been getting a "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted." error. It happens only intermittently, trying a couple of times to save the draft usually works. I am running Wagtail 2.2.2 and Django 2.0.3, and I have `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware'` in my `settings.py` file. Here is the error message:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.

Reason given for failure:
CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a custom implementation of Shibboleth my organization uses for authentication. It seems that if I previewed a page before saving the draft, the CSRF token  was changed by Django, which Shib did not like. In our own code, we extend `RemoteUserMiddleware` to use with Shib. So, we changed that to `PersistentRemoteUserMiddleware` and it seems to be working now.